# sum all values for table column based on class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve the sum of all values in a td based on a specific class. The code does not throw up any errors but my sum keeps resulting in "0".

Do the numerical values have to be specified in a particular way? I saw some other answers here on SO from where have imitated the code, and i dont see any real difference between mine and theirs so im confused as to why mine isnt working.

Here is a tutorial i followed for reference: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/07/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript.html

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.price').each(function() {
    calculateSum();
});
});

 function calculateSum() {

var sum = 0;
//iterate through each td based on class and add the values
    $(".price").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
$('#result').text(sum);    
};
```

Here is my html

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Banana</td>
<td class ="price">50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Apple</td>
 <td class ="price">100</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Code is perfect you just need to change **var value = $(this).text();** insted of **this.value**
    $(td_class_name).each(function() {
                var td_value = $(this).text();
                if(!isNaN(td_value) && td_value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(td_value);
                }       
        });

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You want to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `this.value` (since `<td>`s don't have a "value"):

```
var sum = 0;
// iterate through each td based on class and add the values
$(".price").each(function() {

    var value = $(this).text();
    // add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
});
```

Also, you're looping over your `.price` elements (calling `calculateSum`) multiple times. You can replace

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.price').each(function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
});
```

with

```
$(calculateSum);
```

Comment: Well, I didn't shorten the code that was looping. You were looping twice; one in your `onload` handler and again within the `calculateSum()` function itself. I removed the former. I did shortcut the `ready` handler definition.

Answer (score 5):

I have a JQuery plugin, [**Sumtr**](https://github.com/DLarsen/jquery-sumtr), that handles this pretty well if you want a summary row.

Here is your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CvXnW/) with the plugin.

Comment: That's really neat. I wish i had seen this library sooner. It would have saved me some time. Thanks for responding anyhow. I'll keep an eye on this for future reference.

Comment: this works great, It handles multiple columns as well, which is EXACTLY what i was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: The reason the fiddle doesn't work is that jsfiddle have since enforced strict mime type (check the devloper console for details). Peeked my interest and updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lteou63j/