# SUM table column numbers NOT hidden - using .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As a novice programmer (with higher aspirations!), I have found this forum very educational.

Sadly, I cannot simply join and add comments (min. of 50 credibility points).  Thus, I am forced to open a new question related to a previous post in order to slightly extend the proposed response:

[sum all values for table column based on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293492/sum-all-values-for-table-column-based-on-class/9293516#9293516)

A great response.  However, I have searched around and cannot find a solution for adding column values (numbers), but only if the values are not hidden -  using .hide().

I have one button that hides it's table row when clicked.  In another table, I have another button that specifically shows that row when clicked.  in a similar approach to the referenced solution, I display a sum of the columns.  But, I will always get a total value, unless I can ignore the rows (containing the columns) that I have opted to hide.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

RELEVANT CODE:  CALCULATING SUM

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(calculateSum);

function calculateSum() {

var sum = 0;

// iterates through each td based on class "sumAMT" (perhaps here at the onset I could skip hidden rows?)

$(".sumAMT").each(function() {

    var value = $(this).text();

// adds only if the value is number  (this might also work as a place to determine if this is hidden value)

    if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
});

// Converts to standard comma delimited numeric presentation

function Commas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

// capture of results that are called by the DIV where I want the value displayed (  <DIV id="result"></DIV>  )

$('#result').text('$'+Commas(sum));    
};
</script>
```

RELEVANT CODE: REFERENCED TABLE ROW

```
<tr id="row1" class="Row">
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td width=20px class="sumAMT" id="R1">456.00</td>
  <td width=20px><a href="">
    <button id="row1Remove">remove</button>
  </a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have your code ?

Comment: Add `:visible` to the selector, what's the problem?

Comment: please add your code snippet

Comment: Yeah.. I wasn't sure if I needed to because I referenced another post with basically the same data.  Alas, I have complied.  :)   P.s. not sure the :visible style thang would work here..  do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Barmar's suggestion is to use `$(".sumAMT:visible").each(...`. Give it a try.

Comment: Lol - See.. I knew this was the place for the answer..  I didn't think I could mix the :visible attribute with this..  and when I considered it, I didn't know how to syntactically express it.  In a nut shell:  This solution worked great.  Only, when I would click my buttons to hide a row, the value did not update.  So, I just called the function to recalculate with every click... and presto!  Thanks!  

  calculateSum()-$(".sumAMT").value;
  event.preventDefault();

Comment: Do I need to do anything to mark this as complete or bump up profiles that assisted?  Or, the answer needs to be formally added for this?  (new to such forums)