# Calculating sum of td classes using js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown select menu with various options (i.e. 5, 10, 15, 20...) that represents # of computers. The default select menu value is 5. I am using some js to multiply the dropdown selection by an amount (i.e. 10) and populates a table td with a class of .price-1. So, for example if the user leaves the default selection of 5, the calculated value of .price-1 is 50.

This is working fine.

However, I then need to sum .price-1 with a few other `<td>` classes (i.e. .price-2, .price-3, .price-4...) to get a grand total in $ values that shows in #result.

How can I use js or jQuery to sum these td classes to get the grand total?

Below is my html of my table I need to sum.

```
<table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal"> 
 <tbody> 
  <tr> 
   <td>Item1</td> 
   <td class="price-1">calculated amount populated here</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td>Item2</td> 
   <td class="price-2">calculated amount populated here</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td>Item3</td> 
   <td class="price-3">13</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>Item3</td> 
   <td class="price-4">30</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr class="summary"> 
   <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td> 
   <td id="result" class="totalAmount"> </td> 
  </tr> 
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum all values for table column based on class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293492/sum-all-values-for-table-column-based-on-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all `td` elements either using [attribute value contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) or by second `td` element of `tr` using [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). Now iterate over them using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and get sum using the text inside.

```js
var sum = 0;

$('td[class*="price-"]').each(function() {
  sum += Number($(this).text()) || 0;
});

$('#result').text(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td class="price-1">calculated amount populated here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td class="price-2">calculated amount populated here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item3</td>
      <td class="price-3">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item3</td>
      <td class="price-4">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="summary">
      <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
      <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method as **@rayon** suggested.

```js
$('#result').text([].reduce.call($('td[class*="price-"]'), function(sum, ele) {
  return sum + (Number($(ele).text()) || 0);
}, 0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td class="price-1">calculated amount populated here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td class="price-2">calculated amount populated here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item3</td>
      <td class="price-3">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item3</td>
      <td class="price-4">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="summary">
      <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
      <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `[].reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll('[class*="price-"]'), function(a, b) {
  return a += +b.textContent || 0;
}, 0);` :)

Comment: @Rayon :  Wow that would be nice :) updated with your suggestion... thanks mate :)

Comment: @Rayon and Pranav, this is working for the two <td>s that have values hard coded into the fields (.price-3 and .price-4), but it does not sum the calculated values in .price-1 and .price-2. How can I get it to include the calculated values from .price-1 and .price-2. As I mentioned in my original post, these two are being populated by select dropdown menus that is multiplying the selection by a given number, then posting the results in .price-1 and .price-2. I then need to sum all of these for a grand total. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: One other thing I am finding. I will be hiding the .price-3 and .price-4 <td>s initially and they will be added to the order total if their corresponding checkboxes are selected. However, it seems even if they are hidden, they are still being included in the sum of the order total. Is there a way to not include them in the sum if they are hidden, but include them if they are visible?

Comment: @Rex : if you provided valid number in first two td's then it will add that value also.... if it's not a number then it will treated as `0` ...

Comment: @Rex : if you want to avoid hidden element then update the selector... `$('td[class*="price-"]:not(:hidden)')`

Comment: Thanks Pranav. I updated the selector to avoid the hidden element, and it works, but when I toggle the row to be visible, the sum is not updated to now include the visible row. Also, as far as the calculated content not being included in the sum, is there a way to convert the calculated value into a number so it is included in the sum? I am not sure why is is not being considered a number. I can share with you the js I am using to calculate the .price-1 content if needed.

Comment: @Rex : you need to re-execute the code after toggling

Comment: Pranav - as I am new to js, how will I re-execute the code after the checkbox is selected? Can your code be updated to execute on .change() of the checkboxes? The checkbox ids are: input[name='product_CD'] and input[name='cross_sale_id']. Also, I am still trying to figure out how to convert the .price-1 and .price-2 data into a number so it is included in the sum. I can share my js with you that is used to get the .price-1 & .price-2 values.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dhs3gphz/. Here is the jsfiddle.You can see my select menu and the js that calculates the value of .price-1. You can also see the sum code you provided (currently not working) and you can select the checkboxes to show the hidden table rows. I need the total sum to add all of the row items that are visible. If the checkbox is not selected, the row is hidden and the value should not be included in the sum. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Pranav - you are the man!! it is all working now. The only issue that I am having is in my code, the Total is not summing the default 50 (if the select menu is not changed). Mine is showing 0 until either the select menu is changed or if the checkboxes are selected, then it updates the total. It is working just fine in the jsfiddle, as by default the 50 is being summed. Also, last easy question, how can I return the values in the table in $ format. I think I am ready to give you credit for all of this help!!

Comment: correction - it only includes the .price-1 in the Total if the checkboxes are selected. It does not include the .price-1 in the total regardless how many times I select a new dropdown menu item, until I select one of the checkboxes, then it starts to include them. The checkboxes will not always be selected, so I need the sum to auto sum the .price-1, even if the menu is not changed. Thanks man!

Comment: @Rex :  move the code to document ready handler - https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/dhs3gphz/2/

Comment: I don't see any changes in the jsfiddle code from the original one you supplied. It looks like the document.ready handler was already there, but it still is not working in the jsfiddle. When the page loads, the default $50 (if the defaulted selected 5 from the dropdown) is not summed. When you select a different value from the dropdown, the .price-1 is updated but the sum is not updated. The only way the sum is updated is when the checkboxes are selected.

Comment: OK, that fixed the update when a dropdown menu is selected! Thank you! The last remaining issue I am experiencing is it will not update the sum with the default $50 when the page first loads. It is doing this in jsfiddle just fine, but it will not do it outside jsfiddle. There is a good chance a user will not change the default selection of 5, so I need the sum to automatically update with the default selection when the page loads.

Comment: @Rex : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Object has a direct attribute referring to the number of the matched elements.

```
var sum = $('td[class*="price-"]').length;
$('#result').text(sum);
```