# In HTML or JavaScript, display sum of columns and rows in a table in the table

Tags: html, sum

I have an html table where users can enter values into the table. How can I display the totals of each column and row as well as the total of the totals in the table?

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input value = "0"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value = "0"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
         Total:
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input value = "0"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value = "0"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
         Total:
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Total:
      </td>
      <td>
         Total:
      </td>
      <td>
         Total:
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum values in an HTML table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005062/how-to-sum-values-in-an-html-table-column)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm trying to understand the code in this link. So, it's using Jquery to access the values in the table and them summing them. Okay, I see that and will try doing this. Once I have the sum, how do I inject back into the table to display as a total?

Comment: Another problem is that there are rows and columns in the table. You can traverse across the columns of a row by a class for instance. But then you would have a problem traversing the rows in a column because you can't assign a second class to each <td> or <input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My table:

```
 <table border="1">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <input class="tdvalcol1" value = "0"></input>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input class="tdvalcol2" value = "0"></input>
         </td>
       <td class="totalrow">
        Total:
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input class="tdvalcol1" value = "0"></input></td>
      <td><input class="tdvalcol2" value = "0"></input></td>
      <td class="totalrow">
       Total:
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="totalcol1">
      Total:
      </td>
      <td id="totalcol2">
      Total:
      </td>
      <td id="totalcorner">
      Total:
       </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

the jquery:

```
 col1Sum =0; 
 col2Sum =0;
 rowtotals =0;

 $(".tdvalcol1").each(function(index,value) {
   tdvalue = this.value;
   col1Sum += parseFloat(tdvalue);   
 });    
 $("#totalcol1").text(col1Sum);
    
 $(".tdvalcol2").each(function(index,value) {
    tdvalue = this.value;
    col2Sum += parseFloat(tdvalue);    
 });    
 $("#totalcol2").text(col2Sum);

 $("tr").each(function() {
   rowSum =0;
   var cols = $(this).find("input");
   cols.each(function() {                        
     rowSum += parseFloat(this.value);
   });
   rowtotals +=rowSum;
   $(this).find(".totalrow").text(rowSum)                     
  });
```