# How to count total amount from columns and live table edit and amount change without page reload in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How to count total amount from columns and live table edit and amount change without page reload in Laravel?

```
<div class="table-responsive">    
    <table class="ui celled table" id="LevelOne">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Introducer Id</th>
                <th>Reference Id</th>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>Final Amount</th>
                <th>Status</th>                                            
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                     
            <tr id="client4">
                <td>11</td>
                <td>sdfdsf</td>
                <td>sdfsdf</td>
                <td>sfsdfdsf</td>
                <td>sgfgg</td>
                <td>fsdf@gmail.com</td>
                <td id="name" contenteditable="true">
                    <input type="number" name="PercentageAmount[]" value=1740 >                                                                                      
                </td>
                <td> Approved </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: on the above code i have added a sample data where the final amount will be dynamically added and with page reload i should get the total amount from the num of rows with n++ for the column it should also count total amount from multiple pages from pagination should display in the 1st page of table

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFVkX.png i think you can find the detail by seeing the above link

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293492/sum-all-values-for-table-column-based-on-class

Comment: create a count function, and call it on change saved, or reload.

Comment: You will get a better response here if you edit your question and clarify what you are trying to do, currently it is unclear and likely to be closed.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).